# Ошибка в описании всплывающей подсказки напротив ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Ошибка в описании всплывающей подсказки напротив ответа. Если посмотреть текст:

> Если вопрос решил вашу проблему или помог вам в поиске решения больше
>   других, отметьте его принятым (нажмите повторно, чтобы отменить)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но ведь это не **«вопрос»**, а **«ответ»**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку! Поправил опечатку, добавив несколько инструкций по принятию ответа. Новая строка будет доступна в следующей сборке.